# Unable to auto-attach aspnetdb.mdb in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using website application in VS2010.  It populated data by reading app.config file from another library application.  So I copied the connection string both in library project
and in website application's Web.config.

But when I run the application it throw error as **"unable to  auto attach aspnetdb.mdb"**.

I did configure aspnetdb.mdb or attached it in my application.
Even I did not write any connection string to read aspnetdb.mdb.

My question is by default do we need to attach such mdb in asp.net 4.0 website project? I  have not had such problem in VS2005 and 2008.

I am using SQL Server 2008 professional edition.

Answer (score 0):

No, while creating in VS2010 target webapplication/project/website  to ASP.NET2.0. This will permit to avoid creation of SQL Server dependencies features, files, directories, configs, etc. After creation you can re-target your website/webapp/proj to ASP.NET 4.0 and continue developing already without such dependency.

Update:
The "default" is configurable during VS2010 setup or after.